# Not able to Export Crystal Report to Excel or Word

Tags: asp-classic, crystal-reports, iis-6, reportviewer

While exporting crystal report to Excel or Word , getting the error

```
CRAXDRT Error Occured on Server. 70 : Permission denied
```

I'm using Crystal Report 8 and Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6.0 V. Please help me to resolve this, I'm in critical situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We had this problem here at my company for a long time. It is a COM+ configuration issue. We solved it using these steps:

1 - Find the COM+ package where the components 'CREmfgen.CREmfgen.1' and 'CrystalRuntime.Application.8' are installed; Check that the package is configured as 'Library'. Remove both components from the package.

[image: Remove components from library package]

2 - Create a new package, configured as 'Server';

[image: Create a new COM+ application]

3 - Uncheck 'enforce access checks for this application'.

[image: Remove access checks]

4 - Add the components 'CREmfgen.CREmfgen.1' and 'CrystalRuntime.Application.8' to the package you've just created. The paths are (usually):

C:\Program Files\Seagate Software\Shared\Emfgen.dll

C:\Program Files\Seagate Software\Report Designer Component\craxdrt.dll

[image: Add components to the package]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes "Marcos Brigante" answer did worked for me too.. However when I look at my machine I did not see any library component already configured as said in step 1. The machine configuration was exactly simlar to this and the error was identical too. So since there is no other way to go I went ahead starting form step 2.

Once you did all these, the report stop generating. The report panel start showing with all the buttons but report was blank. Then when I try to export the blank report it worked and didn't give the error we had before..

So seeing some light.. I did few more stuff..

1. In my setup I deleted all in node "Roles", and also "Legacy Compnenets" and
   so I made both nodes empty
2. under property window of the COM + Application, The
   "Activation" tab also changed. I made it use Library Application option
3. Once all done correctly, you should have an Identity
   tab which is completely disabled

Then you will get your reports to work.. so try this if you don't see anything on the COM + section